# Gamebook code throwing errors of undefined, content displayed at bottom of page and images wont load - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I keep getting all sorts of errors with this code. It is supposed to be a Gamebook engine code. A simple one. I am getting all sorts of things wrong with this and I do not know why.

My console keeps saying that line 1 () is undefined 404 not found.

Second, all my content keeps loading at the bottom of the page.

Third... An image should be loading on screen but is not. If I added a movie, it will play the movie, but not show the image.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Fixed code to represent Solution:

```html
<html>
<style>
  objdc {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
  }
</style>



<body>
  <div>
    <div id="StartRoomLoad" name="StartRoomLoad"></div>
    <div id="StartRoomText"></div>
  </div>
</body>



<script type="text/javascript" src="gamebook.js"></script>
<script>
  var GameObjects = {
    'titlescreen': [
      ['RoomName', 'Title Screen'],
      ['RoomDesc', 'Your first room Desc. Go to <objdc id="room2">Room 2</objdc>'],
      ['XRes', '320'],
      ['YRes', '240'],
      ['RmImg', 'http://selmiak.bplaced.net/games/c64/zak/room/74_intro_00_256.png'],
      ['RmMov', '']
    ],
    'room2': [
      ['RoomName', 'Title Screen'],
      ['RoomDesc', 'Your first non-title screen room. Go back to the <objdc id="titlescreen">title screen room</objdc>'],
      ['XRes', '320'],
      ['YRes', '240'],
      ['RmImg', 'http://selmiak.bplaced.net/games/c64/zak/room/74_intro_00_256.png'],
      ['RmMov', '']
    ]
  }
  var GAMENAME = '';
  var OBJECTGLOBAL = ''; //Indicates the current OBJECT loaded.
  var GAMECURPLAYER = ''; //Indicates the current player you control.
  var GAMESCORE = '0';
  var GLOBALSETCLS = false;

  const OBJECTNAME = 0;
  const OBJECTDESC = 1;
  const OBJECTXSIZE = 2;
  const OBJECTYSIZE = 3;
  const OBJECTIMAGE = 4;
  const OBJECTMOVIE = 5;

  function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
  } //end function ParsePlayerInput

  function LoadRoom(roomname) {
    //Loads the specified room and sets the global setting. If a movie file is specified, the engine will play the movie file first. Once the movie is done, it will load the room image. Currently, the video will only play thru once. Once it is played, it will just show an image. If no movie is specified, it will load simply the room background image. If no image is present, it will show no image.

    OBJECTGLOBAL = roomname;

    if (GameObjects[OBJECTGLOBAL][OBJECTMOVIE][1] != '') {

      document.getElementById("StartRoomLoad").innerHTML = '<video id="mainvid" onerror="hidevideo(OBJECTGLOBAL);" onended="hidevideo(OBJECTGLOBAL);" width="100%" height="" autoplay>' + '<source src="' + GameObjects[OBJECTGLOBAL][OBJECTMOVIE][1] + '" type="video/mp4"></video>';
    } else if (GameObjects[OBJECTGLOBAL][OBJECTIMAGE][1] != '') {
      //console.log(GameObjects[OBJECTGLOBAL][OBJECTIMAGE][1]);
      document.getElementById("StartRoomLoad").innerHTML = "<img src='" + GameObjects[OBJECTGLOBAL][OBJECTIMAGE][1] + "' id='RoomBackground' width='" + GameObjects[OBJECTGLOBAL][OBJECTXSIZE][1] + "' height='" + GameObjects[OBJECTGLOBAL][OBJECTYSIZE][1] + "'></image>";
    }
    document.getElementById("StartRoomText").innerHTML = GameObjects[OBJECTGLOBAL][OBJECTDESC][1];
  }

  function hidevideo(roomname) {
    //This function is called once a video is played on room enter. It will close the video and then show the image if there is one. 

    var x = document.getElementById("mainvid");
    var y = document.getElementById("RoomBackground");

    x.style.display = "none";

    if (GameObjects[OBJECTGLOBAL][OBJECTIMAGE][1] != '') {
      document.getElementById("StartRoomLoad").innerHTML = "<img src='" + GameObjects[OBJECTGLOBAL][OBJECTIMAGE][1] + "' id='RoomBackground' width='" + GameObjects[OBJECTGLOBAL][OBJECTXSIZE][1] + "' height='" + GameObjects[OBJECTGLOBAL][OBJECTYSIZE][1] + "'></image>";
    }
  }

  LoadRoom('titlescreen');

  var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('objdc');
  for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i++)
    spans[i].onclick = doRoomLoad;

  function runSPANS() {

    var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('objdc');
    for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i++)
      spans[i].onclick = doRoomLoad;
  }

  //document.getElementsByTagName('objdc').addEventListener('click',doRoomLoad,false);

  function doRoomLoad() {
    //var room = document.getElementById(this.id);

    LoadRoom(this.id);

    runSPANS();
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to say that in IE, it all loads fine. In Chrome.. It is not loading well.

Comment: Where can we find `gamebook.js`?

Comment: Oh sorry.. i forgot to remove that line. Gamebook.js just contains the contents of the variable GameObjects. I copied it into the code above just for convenience.

Comment: Not on a computer right now so I can't say if this will help, but your script tags are outside your HTML tag.

Comment: And your style tags are also outside the HTML tag. And the image appears to be initialized with display:none, which may explain why they don't show up.

Comment: Made those changes... still no image and content still not displayed at the top of the page.

Comment: This is the link its on: http://www.sw-bfs.com/textadv/Gamebook.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it works on IE and not Chrome is that your if statement is relying on a weird equality edge case. Take a look at this line:

```
if (GameObjects[OBJECTGLOBAL][OBJECTMOVIE][1] != ''){
```

`GameObjects[OBJECTGLOBAL][OBJECTMOVIE]` evalutes to the array `["RmMov"]`. Therefore, `GameObjects[OBJECTGLOBAL][OBJECTMOVIE][1]` is `undefined`.

Comparing `undefined` to `''` is a pretty weird equality check, so IE is interpreting this whole statement as `false` and Chrome as `true`.

Anyway, it's assuming that there will be a second value in your array, but there isn't. To fix it, change `['RmMov',]` and `['RmMov']` to `['RmMov', '']`.

That should work.